# Proof of Theorem 8.25 (Ratio Test for a series) - Mathematical Analysis 2nd ed. - Apostol

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

**Theorem 8.25 (Ratio Test)** Given a series $\sum a_n$ of nonzero complex terms, let

$$r=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left |\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\qquad R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left |\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| $$

a) The series $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely if $R<1$.

We want to prove it.

*Proof*. Assume that $R<1$ and choose $x$ so that $R<x<1$. The definition of $R$ implies the existence of $N$ such that $|a_{n+1}/a_n|<x$ if $n\ge N$. Since $x=x^{n+1}/x^n$, this means that

$$\frac {|a_{n+1}|}{x^{n+1}}<\frac {|a_n|}{x^n}\leq \frac {|a_N|}{x^N}, \qquad if n\ge N, \qquad(1)$$
and hence $|a_n|\leq cx^n$ if $n\ge N$, where $c=|a_N|x^{-N}$. Statement a) now follows by applying the comparison test.

Now my questions are:

1. What is Mr. Apostol doing when he says "Since $x=x^{n+1}/x^n$"?
2. How can I have $\frac {|a_n|}{x_n}\leq \frac {|a_N|}{x^N}$ in $(1)$?

Note:

My first question was trivial. Evidently I was confused by something totally insignificant. He is just saying the you can write $x$ as $x^{n+1}/x^n$.

Thank you for your patient help.

Comment: It's hard to understand your first question. I have no idea what you're asking. Can you try to rephrase it, please?

Comment: Are you wanting to ask why does he rewrite $x$ as $\frac {x^{n+1}}{x^n}?$

Comment: I can't understand why $x=x^{n+1}/x^n$ pops up...

Comment: @Charlie: I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To get the left inequality of (1). Notice that we've already had $|a_{n+1}/a_n|\lt x.$ Hence, we have
$$|a_{n+1}/a_n|\lt x=x^{n+1}/x^n\Rightarrow \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{x^{n+1}}\lt \frac{|a_n|}{x^n}.$$

2) Since we have the left inequality of (1), we know that a sequence
$$\frac{|a_n|}{x_n}$$
is monotone decreasing sequence. Noticing that $N\le n,$ we have
$$\frac{|a_n|}{x^n}\le \frac{a_N}{x^N}.$$

Comment: Very useful. My last doubt is this: Why $x$ equals $x^{n+1}/x^n$ and not another thing?

Comment: I don't understand your question. $x^{n+1}/x^n=x^{(n+1)-n}=x^1=x.$